# Binary file to base64 nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-speech

I'm getting a binary audio file when I call the api tts.speech.microsoft.com and I would like to transform this binary into a base64 string.

I've been trying a lot of things, for example:

```
Buffer.from(body, "binary").toString("base64");
```

does not work.

I'm not sure 'binary' is the exact word, but it's not a readable format.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify "does not work"? The code looks correct. Also where does the binary data come from? Some things such as fs.readFile has shortcuts to convert to base64.

Comment: I call this endpoint from a phone, and try to play the sound. When I try to do it with another base64 string it works so I know the code on this part is ok. @Dominic

Comment: Where does the other base64 string come from? My hunch is that your original binary content is not correct/the same format as the working one

Comment: it comes from google cloud.

Comment: when I try to save the file from my computer and read it with:
require("fs").writeFile("out.mp3", content, "base64", function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });

Comment: the file is not readable...

Comment: You can see here there is nothing wrong with the conversion code - https://repl.it/@DominicTobias/WorstUtilizedComputers (converting binary "apple" to base64 and back). So the issue is in code you haven't posted, most likely your binary data is incorrect compared to the working one

Comment: Yeah I can see this part is correct, but when I try to save the file and read it locally from my computer, the file is not readable:
      const content = Buffer.from(body, "binary").toString("base64");
      require("fs").writeFile("out.wav", content, "base64", function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
Maybe the response is not in binary ?

Comment: What format is `body` in? Is it just incoming as a buffer/byte array?

Comment: @Alex body is a string. The only solution I found is to save the file with createwritestream , and then read the file in base64 and send it.
This is not ideal of course, but I've been playing with it for hours...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you were following the section [`Make a request and save the response`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-nodejs-text-to-speech#make-a-request-and-save-the-response) of the offical document `Quickstart: Convert text-to-speech using Node.js` to write your code, as below.

> ```
> var request = require('request');
>
> let options = {
>     method: 'POST',
>     baseUrl: 'https://westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/',
>     url: 'cognitiveservices/v1',
>     headers: {
>         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
>         'cache-control': 'no-cache',
>         'User-Agent': 'YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME',
>         'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat': 'riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm',
>         'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml'
>     },
>     body: body
> };
>
> function convertText(error, response, body){
>   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
>     console.log("Converting text-to-speech. Please hold...\n")
>   }
>   else {
>     throw new Error(error);
>   }
>   console.log("Your file is ready.\n")
> }
> // Pipe the response to file.
> request(options, convertText).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('sample.wav'));
> ```

So I change the offical code above to create a function `encodeWithBase64` to encode `body` with Base64.

```
function encodeWithBase64(error, response, body){
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var strBase64 = Buffer.from(body).toString('base64');
    console.log(strBase64);
  }
  else {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
  console.log("Your file is encoded with Base64.\n")
}
// Pipe the response to file.
request(options, convertText);
```

Or you can use the npm packages [`base64-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-stream) and [`get-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-stream) to get the string with Base64 from `body`.

```
var base64 = require('base64-stream');
const getStream = require('get-stream');
(async () => {
    var encoder = new base64.Base64Encode();
    var b64s = request(options).pipe(encoder);
    var strBase64 = await getStream(b64s);
    console.log(strBase64);
})();
```

Otherwise, [`stream-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-string) also can do it.

```
var base64 = require('base64-stream');
const ss = require('stream-string');
var encoder = new base64.Base64Encode();
var b64s = request(options).pipe(encoder);
ss(b64s).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```