# My response is not an url, How can I display an image which is not url using base64 and response does not contain bodyBytes?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, encoding, base64

My api is `get()` and the response contains `data` like this

[image]

The above image which you can see is my image which I want to display it on web using reactjs. ANd I dont know how can this be done.
The get api returns  `data, config, headers, request, status,statusText`
I want the data above which I some weird format, my image to be displayed. I dont know how to do it. Need help

---

**Update:**

`action`

```
export const getFileImage = (payload) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        console.log("Payload--->",payload);
        let response = await axios.get('/api/movies/' + payload.movieId + '/document/' + payload.genre.toLowerCase().toString());
        console.log("Response----->",response);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error");
    }
}
```

Output of **response**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you ask backend developer or api provider about this issue?

Comment: yes. it works when accessed through app. but when called from web it does not work

Comment: through which app? mobile? android or something like that

Comment: Yes. mobile. android. From mobile, getting response with bodyBytes with status as 200. But when I call the get api from react, it just returns status as 200 and data which in the format above

Comment: What do the response headers tell you? Can you add those to your question along with your react code?

Comment: From app, I am getting bodyBytes in response. But when I try calling the same api from web, I do not get any bodyBytes

Comment: i think it should returns by something like base64 format for web... apparently android is able to show that format

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh How do I do it on web? reactjs?

Comment: your response is in binary, you have to convert it to base64 before displaying. you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54439463/3625973) answer. But it would be better to get the response in base64 itself. Mobile app and web apps are not the same, web apps run on browser, not on the host os, so you cannot create files like mobile apps can on the file storage.

Comment: @itiDi In fact, this API returns directly the photo's code, I mean something like binary and basically android is able to show that... you can not use that format for web, I think it would be better to ask backend developer for new route that returns base64 codes or an option to convert output

Comment: So, is it better to do the base64 at the backend and then send its response to front end? @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh

Comment: @itiDi yes, exactly ! because you can use easily base64 for UI side

Comment: okay @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh can you write an answer to this then? As I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you asked for an example and I wrote this answer...

You can use base64 format to show Images in your React component:

```
render(){
    {this.state.image ? <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.image}`}/>: ''}
}
```

I think it would be better to ask backend developer or API provider to convert output for web and your requirements in React JS.

Comment: Yes sure. I will try this out and tell the backend developer to send the converted image itself.

Comment: I tried this. it shows the image. but when i say open in new tab `target="_blank"` it does not open in new tab. It gives me blank tab